# cant get correct time from unix timestamp

Tags: php, unix

I cant convert the unix timestamp tp the correct time. The date is OK but my time is 13 hours out. I am using php 5.6 with cakephp3. My webpage displays the current correct time to confuse matters

```
 i get 'am' and not 'pm' with 1hr slow  
 date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne'); 
 $melbourne = time(); echo gmdate('d-m-Y H:i a', $melbourne);

 //Error: Call to a member function setTimestamp() on null 
$date->setTimestamp(1516769611.7392); //should be   2018-01-24 15:53:31
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
//i did include this in controller for cakephp3 use Cake\I18n\Time;


 $timestamp=$item['submit_time']; //1516769611.7392
 echo  gmdate('d-m-Y H:i:s', $timestamp); //24-01-2018 04:53:31 time is wrong 

 $time = Time::createFromTimestamp( $timestamp);
 echo $time;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php

Comment: this may have something to do with using `gmdate` and where / if the DateTime default timezone is set to something that isn't GMT/UTC

Comment: yes i suspected something like this but my current time I display on the page is correct as this works date("g:i a");  so what do I do?

Comment: don't use `gmdate` and instead use `date` ?

Comment: yes this works so could you put this up as an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting timezone at top of your code

```
date_default_timezone_set(your_time_zone);
```

Comment: no this does work. Please take down answer  as i get  am and not pm with 1hr slow date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
                                     $melbourne = time();
                                      echo  gmdate('d-m-Y H:i a', $melbourne);